# Project in VS 2015 decompiled by dotpeek reporting ambiguous error on same class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, decompiling, jetbrains-ide

i have some small app, created in C# and its working. But when i decompile it with jetbrains dotpeek and open it in Visual Studio 2015 it shows me error

**The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties 'MainWindow.InitializeComponent()' and 'MainWindow.InitializeComponent()'**

Application is easy, just one class and im curious why it shows error, that method is in same class? I made a tripple check and code contains only single declaration of this method.

Also it contains error
**The type 'MainWindow' already contains a definition for '_contentLoaded'**
which will be probably caused by same issue... Also in same class, and only one copy of this class, and triple checked for another occurence of declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of times debuggers and decompillers give result code with errors. They are maded only for understanding and fixing problems in programs without source code. If you have sources - you can debug your app without decompilation and save a lot of time. If you want compare code (original/decompiled), you can use WinMerge or other programs for it. Also you can try other decompilers, like ILSpy or .NET Reflector.